# Unable to change etc/passwd in Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, passwd

I'm running Ubuntu for Windows, and I created a second user. I go into the users /etc directory to edit the passwd file so that I can use a custom shell on login, but there are some problems.

Running `emacs passwd` doesn't allow me to make changes for permission reasons.
So I try to the command `sudo emacs passwd` and it tells me that I'm not in the list of sudoers and that it will be reported.

Since I'm on ubuntu for windows, I don't think I can run the safe mode recovery fix, so I'm at a deadend.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem a while back too. Hopefully you get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just realized a way to fix your problem.

Login to the primary user and sudo edit the file.